# Adding two chars in c++

Tags: c++

I have 2 chars. I want to add them like this:

- 1 char: `11000010`
- 2 char: `00010000`
- result: `00010000 11000010`

my result should be an int. (the other bytes on the left side should be 0)

what I am doing is this:

```
int i = (c2 <<8) + c1;
```

but that gives me a totally different value than expected. ( also when I replace the `+` with an `|`)

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't think "add" is the operation you're after.  You don't add 1 and 2 to get 12.

Comment: @DrEval: `+` would work in this instance.

Comment: *"but that gives me a totally different value than expected"* - What does it give you?

Comment: @DrEval What he's trying to do is the binary equivalent of `1*10 + 2 = 12`. Shifting is multiplication by a power of 2.

Comment: If you handle raw bytes, then you're not working with "chars". And since you don't work with "chars", avoid using the `char` type as well. Instead use the `int8_t` or `uint8_t` types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`char` is `signed` on your platform.

If you use `unsigned char` for your types for `c2` and `c1` then the implicit promotion to `int` for each term in your expression will have the effect you are after.

Comment: Sign extension rears its head again

Answer (score 4):

You can use multiplication instead of shifting:

```
int i = (int)c2 * 256 + c1;
```